# Error while creating delve clone

Tags: sharepoint-online, delve

I have followed the video in this [link](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/10/creating-delve-clone-using-content.html) to create a clone of delve site.

But I am getting the error on page:-

> We didn't understand your search terms. Make sure you're using the
>   proper < a
>   href="javascript:HelpWindowKey('WSSEndUser_SearchTips');">syntax.

I am not able to get solution to this error, is there any other way I can create a page with similar user related information as on the delve page.